# vbs additional error information

Tags: web, vbscript, error-handling

Is there any option to get more information about what caused an error in vbs than the the properties `err.description`, `err.source`, `err.erl` and `err.number`? Helpfile and and HelpContext are not what I'm looking for. More like `function 'foo' does not exist`.

Those I found on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka13cy19(v=vs.90).aspx, but maybe there is an undocumented function or different error handling?

Comment: Whats your question? Be specific

Comment: It is a generic question, because I don't have a specific problem, but a generic one. I'd like my error messages to contain code parts (as I mentioned in the example).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on context and error you might be able to get some additional information through other means (for instance by using `TypeName` to get type information about the content of variables), but there is no magic spell to make the variable `Err` provide more information than what the runtime environment puts in it.